# Join many to many tables optionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have below tables

User

```
user_id  name
101      Tony
102      Skyle
103      Kenne
```

Intrest

```
intrest_id intrest_name
201          Eating
202          Sleeping
203          Drinking
```

Hobby

```
hobby_id  hobby_name
301         Smoking
302         Hiking
303         Browsing
```

User_Intrest

```
user_id  intrest_id
101      201
102      201
102      202
103      201
103      202
103      203
```

User_Hobby

```
user_id  hobby_id
101      301
102      301
102      302
103      301
103      302
103      303
```

Now to find user ids who have both interests `Eating` and `Sleeping` I have written

```
select u.user_id
from user u, intrest i, user_intrest ui
where u.user_id = ui.user_id 
and i.intrest_id = ui.intrest_id and i.intrest_name in ('Eating', 'Sleeping')
group by u.user_id
having count(i.intrest_name) = 2
```

Output

```
user_id
102
103
```

Same as above I also can find user ids with hobbies `Smoking`, `Hiking`, `Browsing` as below

```
select u.user_id
from user u, hobby h, user_hobby uh
where u.user_id = uh.user_id 
and h.hobby_id = uh.hobby_id and h.hobby_name in ('Smoking', 'Hiking', 'Browsing')
group by u.user_id
having count(i.intrest_name) = 3
```

Output

```
user_id
    103
```

Now I want to mix these two optionally in a way that if only interests are passed then users with those interests will be found or if only hobbies are passed then users with those hobbies are found or if both interests and hobbies are passed then users with those interests as well as hobbies are found

Update:
This is part of a spring data rest api with native query where query parameters are optional. Below is a working example for finding users for intrests. Now I want to expand it to include hobbies so both will be used if both are passed in the request to find users

```
@RestResource(path = "getUserByIntrestsAndHobbies", rel = "getUserByIntrestsAndHobbies")
    @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE (COALESCE(:intrests, NULL) IS NOT NULL AND u.userId IN (SELECT u.userId " +
            "FROM User u, Intrest i, UserIntrest ui " +
            "WHERE u.userId = ui.userId AND i.intrestId = ui.intrestId " +
            "AND i.intrestName IN (:intrests) " +
            "GROUP BY u.userId " +
            "HAVING (:intrestsSize IS NULL OR :intrestsSize = count(i.intrestName))))"
    )
    Page<User> getUsersByIntrestsAndHobbies(@Param("intrests") List<String> intrests,
                                                                           @Param("intrestsSize") Long intrestsSize,
                                                                           @Param("hobbies") List<String> hobbies,
                                                                           @Param("hobbiesSize") Long hobbiesSize,
                                                                           Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: For a start, stop using implicit (comma separated) joins as they have been obsolete for many years now. Instead use explicit joins.

Comment: What do you mean by *only interests are passed*?

Comment: This query should be able to accept only intrests and give users who have those intrests if hobbies are not passed @GMB

Comment: Right, but how are the values *passed* to the query?

Comment: This is spring data rest native query where query params are optional. I just put the query instead of entire repository method

Comment: But we need to see what form the parameters arrive as... your query doesn't include parameters - if you were to re-write it with parameters we could help you. You've shown us literal values, but as thats not real life we need more detail.

Comment: updated to include spring data repository method that has these as optional query parameters @DaleK

Comment: Also the query which you wrote is missing the join on Interest table but I.intrest_name is being used in the HAVING clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem becomes a lot clearer when you use explicit joins (instead of the implicit, depreciated, comma-separated joins). You then see that you need to use `left` joins to allow a record to be returned when there is match.

```
select u.[user_id]
from [user] u
left join user_intrest ui on ui.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
left join intrest i on i.intrest_id = ui.intrest_id and i.intrest_name in ('Eating', 'Sleeping')
left join user_hobby uh on uh.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
left join hobby h on h.hobby_id = uh.hobby_id and h.hobby_name in ('Smoking', 'Hiking', 'Browsing')
group by u.[user_id]
having count(distinct i.intrest_name) = 2 and count(distinct h.hobby_name) = 3;
```

- Its best practice not to use reserved words such as `user` or `user_id` as you will always need to escape them.
- Aside from the `id` column, there is no need to prepend the table name to a column name e.g. `hobby_name` should just be `name` - you're just giving yourself more typing as it stands.
- Interest is not spelt Intrest :)
- If you provide DDL/DML for the sample data then its a lot easier for us to test.

Comment: Appreciate for the suggestions. This is not real data I just mocked up to post here. This query is not giving the expected result as per the data. individual left joins are working for intrest and hobby but when mixed it not working. For example User 103 have quoted intrests and hobbies but the query returned empty

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select i.userid
from (select ui.userid
      from user_interest ui join
           interest i
           on i.interest_id = ui.interest_id 
      where i.interest_name in ('Eating', 'Sleeping')
      group by ui.userid
      having count(*) = 2
     ) i join
     (select uh.userid
      from user_hobby uh join
           hobby h
           on uh.hobby_id = i.hobby_id 
      where h.hobby_name in ('Smoking', 'Hiking', 'Browsing')
      group by uh.userid
      having count(*) = 3
     ) h
     on i.userid = h.userid;
```

This counts along each dimension separately, so the counts are accurate.

Comment: That doesn't work if only interests or hobbies are passed in though - at least not the way OP is currently writing their query.